# How to Convert Static Query to Dynamic Query?

Tags: php, mysql

My question is that how can I changed this below written query to Dynamic Query.
table structure and query are as below:

classes table

```
class_id              class_name
  1                     1st
  2                     2nd
```

fee_type table

```
fee_type_id         fee_name
   1                Admission Fee
   2                Tution Fee
```

fee_plan table

```
fee_plan_id         fee_type_id       class_id      fee_value
    1                     1                1            3000
    2                     2                1            400
```

fee_write_off table

```
fee_write_off_id           fee_id           months
     1                        1              4
     2                        2              1
     3                        2              2
     4                        2              3
     5                        2              4
     6                        2              5
     7                        2              6
     8                        2              7
     9                        2              8
    10                        2              9
    11                        2              10
    12                        2              11
    13                        2              12
```

etc.

How to build dynamic query like that if month names are selected from frontend checkboxes using php loop or mysql stored procedure cursur loop etc I dont know how to perform this query dynamically.

```
SELECTfee_name,
   SUM(CASE months  WHEN  4 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `April`,
   SUM(CASE months WHEN  5 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `May`,
   SUM(CASE months WHEN  6 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `June`,
   SUM(CASE months WHEN  7 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `July`,
   SUM(CASE months WHEN  8 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `August`,
   SUM(CASE months WHEN  9 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `September`,
   SUM(CASE months WHEN 10 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `October`,
   SUM(CASE months WHEN 11 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `November`,
   SUM(CASE months WHEN 12 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `December`,
   SUM(CASE months WHEN  1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `January`,
   SUM(CASE months WHEN  2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `February`,
   SUM(CASE months WHEN  3 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `March`,
   SUM(amount) AS `Total`
FROM fee_type
JOIN fee_writeoff USING(fee_id)
JOIN fee_plan USING(fee_id)
GROUP BY fee_name WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Wow is that one statement!

Comment: What exactly do you want to make dynamic?

Comment: I have edited my question. I want fee_value calculated dynamically. based on selected months from front end checkboxes.

Comment: you can use `if()` statements to check if the front end month is selected, and just concatenate your query string if it is -> `$query = "SELECT fee_name,"; if(isset($_POST['April'])) $query .= " SUM(CASE months  WHEN  4 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS \`April\`"; ... $query .= "SUM(amount) AS \`Total\` FROM fee_type ..."`